# Error while Dockerizing a CRUD RESTful API with Go, MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm getting issue while running `docker compose up` , You can see my `docker-compose.yaml` file that I wrote for running the web API with MySQL db. I've also attached the error I'm facing currently. It'll be a great help if you can help me in this regard. thanks.

```
    version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: web_api
    build: .
    ports: 
      - 8080:5000
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - api:/usr/src/app/
    depends_on:
      - webapi-mysql          
    networks:
      - webapi


  webapi-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.26
    container_name: db_mysql
    ports: 
      - 3308:3306
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=${DB_HOST} 
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - database_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - webapi

volumes:
  api:
  database_mysql:                  

# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  webapi:
    driver: bridge
```

Error is coming up in my CLI, as follows

```
Attaching to db_mysql, web_api
db_mysql        | 2021-11-08 13:20:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.
db_mysql        | 2021-11-08 13:20:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_mysql        | 2021-11-08 13:20:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.
db_mysql        | 2021-11-08 13:20:28+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: MYSQL_USER="root", MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD are for configuring a regular user and cannot be used for the root user
db_mysql        |     Remove MYSQL_USER="root" and use one of the following to control the root user password:
db_mysql        |     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
db_mysql        |     - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
db_mysql        |     - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
web_api         | 2021/11/08 13:20:31 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
db_mysql exited with code 1
web_api exited with code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried updating your config file according to the detailed suggestions in the error message?

Comment: You are trying to connect to `tcp 127.0.0.1:3306`, but you have opened 3308 port in the MySQL container. Either you modify the port or update the port configuration

Comment: Thanks @Shadow! Yes, I did that, It fixes one of my errors but still getting connection issues. Could you plz take a look at my .yaml file again if I need to refactor? 
After the fix/changes, error comes up as follows:
`Attaching to db_mysql, web_api
db_mysql        | 2021-11-09 06:42:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.
web_api         | 2021/11/09 06:41:36 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused`

Comment: Plz, find my repo as well for your reference [link](https://github.com/afzal442/go_prac/tree/main/GO_Exercise/T1). thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the db configuration in your app to connect to `webapi-mysql` instead of `127.0.0.1`. Every container gets its own unique address. Docker will create a fake DNS record for `webapi-mysql` that points to the correct IP address at that time.

Comment: thanks @caveman for pointing out, I couldn't get where to change. Could you look here again on my repo itself i.e. https://github.com/afzal442/go_prac/tree/main/GO_Exercise/T1

Comment: Here you define your database connection string, I think that is it: https://github.com/afzal442/go_prac/blob/1ccbc27e04d7174450b87dcc9b6a434f1ce4a434/GO_Exercise/T1/controllers/controllers.go#L71

Comment: after workaround, I discovered the same issue. something like below;
`Attaching to db_mysql, web_api
db_mysql  | 2021-11-09 11:39:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.
db_mysql  | 2021-11-09 11:39:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_mysql  | 2021-11-09 11:39:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.
db_mysql  | 2021-11-09T11:39:08.118776Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) starting as process 1
`

Comment: `db_mysql  | 2021-11-09T11:39:08.240601Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
web_api   | 2021/11/09 11:39:08 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
web_api exited with code 1
db_mysql  | 2021-11-09T11:39:09.501674Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
`

Comment: `db_mysql  | 2021-11-09T11:39:10.354847Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
db_mysql  | 2021-11-09T11:39:10.355065Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.26'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
web_api   | 2021/11/09 11:39:12 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
web_api exited with code 0`

Comment: Could you @caveman plz also take a look again? thanks https://github.com/afzal442/go_prac/blob/fc8f30777210a605acb66b81990352c87b580680/GO_Exercise/T1/controllers/controllers.go#L73

Comment: https://github.com/afzal442/go_prac/blob/fc8f30777210a605acb66b81990352c87b580680/GO_Exercise/T1/controllers/controllers.go#L77 you are still trying to connect to `127.0.0.1`, your db is in a separate container you need to change it to `db_mysql` or `webapi-mysql` (I am not sure if the `container_name` option also applies to the generated DNS name)